# Difference between pulse coupling and diffusive coupling In biological oscillators

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, neurophysiology, biophysics, systems-biology

1. What are the differences between pulse coupling found among neuron cells and diffusive coupling found in cells that exhibit calcium waves?
2. Moreover, in both methods, is it a strict requirement that the cells have to be adjacent to each other or at a distance from each other.

I know this is not a mathematical forum, but can anyone answer the next question or at least point out some books/article where I can learn them.

3. How can we represent pulse and diffusive coupling mathematically?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to in Q1. What calcium waves? Can you give us a reference?

Comment: @Memming Intracellular calcium waves. [For example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8396478)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

3. As for a book on the topic of mathematical modeling of coupled neural oscillators, you can start with:

   - Wilson, H. R. (1999) **Spikes, Decisions & Actions**: Dynamical Foundations of Neuroscience, Oxford University Press, Oxford UK. [author's copy](http://cvr.yorku.ca/webpages/wilson.htm), [amz](http://amzn.to/22BTZXT)